# SQL how to change columns value in next 2 records

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which contains two columns, one named "ID", and the other is "FLG". I need to add anther column "FLG1" that based on column "FLG".

The process logic is that if one record is "Y" in this table, then the next 2 records should be both "N" in "FLG1", if it is "N", then just keep it in "FLG1".

For example:

For record which ID=2 and FLG=Y,then FLG1 of this record should be "Y", but for the next 2 records（ID=3,4), FLG1 should be "N", though their FLG is "Y".

The expected result is as below:

[image]

I have tried many ways for days but failed and I don't want a stored procedure, I just want SQL query scripts for the implementation.

Here is the scripts for the data:

```
 select 1 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 2 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 3 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 4 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 5 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 6 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 7 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 8 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 9 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 10 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 11 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 12 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 13 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 14 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 15 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 16 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 17 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 18 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 19 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 20 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 21 as ID, 'N' as FLG from dual union all
 select 22 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual union all
 select 23 as ID, 'Y' as FLG from dual
```

Comment: Could you add the expected result as per your explanation ?

Comment: I suppose your sample data is wrong. Do you really want the ID to be a string? Then the sort order would be '1', '10', '11', ... '2', '20', ... Remove the quotes for the IDs to get this correct.

Comment: The result image you have linked to does not match your description. ID 5 would have to get 'N', because the ID 4 has 'Y' in the table. Which is correct, your description or the image?

Comment: I'm reading the requirement as that Ys should be treated as runs of three, and for each of those, only the first Y is preserved; four Ys in a row is treated as two separate runs. Is that right?

Comment: Hmm, no, that doesn't match your output either; why is 10 N rather than Y? Does a Y have to be followed by at least to Ns before you see another Y? Please edit your question to explain your logic more fully.

Comment: @Alex Poole: I am afraid scofile wants an iterative process here. Rather than at the table's 'Y' they are looking at the generated 'Y'. If this is really what they are after, a recursive query would solve this.

Comment: the image is correct, my description may not writing well

Comment: The proper definition should be IMO: *replace Y with N in two rows following (a not replaced) Y*

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAG` to see the previous two rows. Then use `CASE WHEN` to decide what to show.

```
select 
  id,
  flg,
  case
    when lag(flg) over(order by id) = 'Y' or lag(flg, 2) over(order by id) = 'Y' then 'N'
    else flg
  end as flg1
from mytable
order by id;
```

**Your description is wrong. You want to iterate through your rows for which you'd use a recursive query in SQL.**

Number your rows first, because there can always be gaps in a table's IDs. Then use a recursive query to loop through the rows. I think this is the straight-forward to approach this.

```
with numbered as (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from mytable t)
, cte (id, flg, flg1, prev_flg1, rn) as
(
  select id, flg, flg, null, rn from numbered where rn = 1
  union all
  select
    t.id,
    t.flg,
    case
      when cte.flg1 = 'Y' or cte.prev_flg1 = 'Y' then 'N'
      else t.flg
    end,
    cte.flg1,
    t.rn
  from cte 
  join numbered t on t.rn = cte.rn + 1
)
select id, flg, flg1
from cte
order by id;
```

Comment: This does not work; IDs 5, 8, 10 and 12 should all be `Y` but this sets them to `N`.

Comment: @MTO - 10 should be 'N', apparently, which complicates things, and made my answer wrong too...

Comment: The description `"The process logic is that if one record is "Y" in this table ..."` in the request is wrong. It is not about the 'Y' in the table, but about the 'Y' in the result rows already created - an iterative request. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the rows sequentially and calculate whether to show the row before you can calculate whether to show row following it; this means you need a recursive (or hierarchical) query.

You need to split the rows up into triplets of sequential rows such that each triplet starts with a `FLG = 'Y'` row and then all rows that are not in such a triplet or are in the second or third rows of the triplet will have a `FLG1` value of `N`.

Like this:

```sql
WITH find_triplets ( id, flg, flg_count ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         flg,
         DECODE( flg, 'Y', 1, 0 )
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  id = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id,
         t.flg,
         CASE f.flg_count
         WHEN 0
         THEN DECODE( t.flg, 'Y', 1, 0 )
         ELSE MOD( f.flg_count + 1, 3 )
         END
  FROM   find_triplets f
         INNER JOIN table_name t
         ON ( t.id = f.id + 1 )
)
SELECT id,
       flg,
       CASE
       WHEN flg = 'Y' AND flg_count = 1
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END as flg1
FROM   find_triplets
ORDER BY id
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> ```
> ID | FLG | FLG1
> -: | :-- | :---
>  1 | N   | N   
>  2 | Y   | Y   
>  3 | Y   | N   
>  4 | Y   | N   
>  5 | Y   | Y   
>  6 | Y   | N   
>  7 | Y   | N   
>  8 | Y   | Y   
>  9 | N   | N   
> 10 | Y   | N   
> 11 | N   | N   
> 12 | Y   | Y   
> 13 | N   | N   
> 14 | N   | N   
> 15 | N   | N   
> 16 | Y   | Y   
> 17 | N   | N   
> 18 | N   | N   
> 19 | N   | N   
> 20 | N   | N   
> 21 | N   | N   
> 22 | Y   | Y   
> 23 | Y   | N
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fda1a0b45e889136299439af83212c8d)*

Comment: this is really really amazing, thanks a  lot!!!! The issue had been taking me some days long

Comment: @scofile Updated with a much simpler query.

Answer (score 1):

In my misinterpretation of the question, this is a pretty simple gaps-and-islands problem.  See the edit below for an improved answer.  I would suggest using the difference of row numbers to define the islands.  The definition of the flag is then just checking the row number on each group of `'Y'` values:

```
select id, flg,
       (case when flg = 'Y' and
                  mod(row_number() over (partition by flg, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by id), 3) = 1
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end) as flg1
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by flg order by id) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c3a9ae7284604a686575c35212476a3c) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to update the flag, I would recommend using `merge`.

Note:  I would also expect this to be faster (perhaps much faster) than a recursive CTE approach.

EDIT:

Alex makes a really good point.  I think this requires a recursive CTE.  If you have a large amount of data, it might be possible to optimize it by splitting the data into groups where you have multiple `'N'`s in a row.  Your question doesn't mention data size.

I would approach this as:

```
with tt as (
       select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from t
     ),
     cte (seqnum, id, flg, flg1, counter) as (
      select seqnum, id, flg, flg,
             (case when flg = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.seqnum, tt.id, tt.flg,
             (case when cte.counter in (1, 2) then 'N'
                   when tt.flg = 'Y' then 'Y'
                   else 'N'
              end),
             (case when cte.counter in (1, 2) then cte.counter + 1
                   when tt.flg = 'Y' then 1
                   else 0
              end)
      from cte join
            tt
            on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Basically, this walks through the data and finds the first `'Y'`.  At that point, it sets a counter to `1`.  In the next two rows, the counter is incremented, regardless of the value of the flag.  Then it goes back to looking for a `'Y'` to repeat the process.

Amusingly, this seems like a pretty simple operation to implement using a Turing machine.  Usually, it is not obvious how to implement such things.

Interestingly, if you put all the flags in a string, regular expressions solve the problem very simply:

```
select flgs,
       substr(regexp_replace(flgs, 'Y(..|.$|$)', 'YNN'), 1, length(flgs)) as flg1s
from (select listagg(flg, '') within group (order by id) as flgs
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: That's the same as my (deleted) answer I think; but gets the wrong result for ID 10 - should be N, not Y. Unclear from the original description, but comments state the results in the image are what is really needed.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . I've modified the answer.  Interestingly, this is almost trivial using regular expressions.